# Multiple Power BI Report Server pointing to the same ReportServerDB?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Can I have multiple Power BI Report Servers ( in different hosts ) simultaneously pointing to the same ReportServerDB and sharing the same Reports ( LiveConnection's to SSAS Multidimensional )?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yes, scale-out deployment is one of the supported scenarios, where multiple SSRS or Power BI Report Server instances share a single reports DB.

For more information see [High availability in SQL Server Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/high-availability-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Configure a Native Mode Report Server Scale-Out Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-native-mode-report-server-scale-out-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15) articles.